# .NET / WinForms - Clear a Sort on a DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, grid, gridview-sorting

What is the proper method to tell a DataGridView to stop sorting?

I have a "screen" where I tell the grid programatically to sort by column 4 and ascending.
When I switch to another area I want the same grid to come in 'default'/no sort.
I'm removing all the columns and adding new ones. The sort remains on the 4th column.

I don't see a way to do this with the Sort() method. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. But I'm even switching DataSources. I'm calling DataSource = null and Columns.Clear before the switch.

Comment: I'd like to be able to allow a refresh but save the sort order. But if the user switches what they want to look at (via a TreeView) then I'd like the sort order to go away. Is this a bug? I've tried a few things, I can't figure out a way to make it go away.

Comment: Frustrating that the enum ListSortDirection has no .None value, but SortOrder does. You use SortOrder to get the value from the DataGridView but you use ListSortDirection to set it.

Comment: The switching data sources throws my theory out.  Hopefully the additional info gets you some hits.

Answer (score 8):

I've accessed the sort on the BindingSource directly:

`((BindingSource)_dgv.DataSource).Sort = string.Empty;`

Comment: Thanks!  I just used BindingSource.Sort = "" and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 7):

From [MSN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e78ff5d3-6163-4413-b0b1-3cd3f7d561ad):

The DataGridView is bound to a DataView and not the Table directly, so you need to set:

`DataTable.DefaultView.Sort = String.Empty`

Effectively clearing the sorting on the table and thereby the grid that is bound to it.  This appears to require a Refresh of the DataGridView, unless you are using 2005, and then you can use a separate binding manager.

Answer (score 2):

in the same domain as the answer from user2268720.. not the cleanest solution, but did the job for me with an unbound DGV:

```
            if (dgv.SortedColumn != null) {
                DataGridViewColumn col = dgv.SortedColumn;
                col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
                col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
            }
```

Comment: I found setting the sorted column's sort glyph direction to none clears it. `dgv.SortedColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None`

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but there is of course no good definition for 'unsorted'. Can't you sort on a (hidden) column, like an ID?

Comment: good idea. I do have a fake column that I add to the DataTable after DataAdapter loads it called "row_number" all it is used for is pagination (if I choose to turn that on). +1. This might be my answer.

Comment: There are restrictions on sorting on 'fake' columns in combination with a DataSource, see MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the grid's itemsource to Nothing, then set it back again to the table's DefaultView

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today too.  I have a `DataGridView` that swaps out its `DataSource` (a `DataTable`) regularly.  I was able to finally remove the sort that the user specified when the user clicked a column-header using the following code:

```
    If dgv.SortedColumn IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgv.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dt_Sender As DataTable = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, DataTable)
        dt_Sender.DefaultView.Sort = dt_Sender.Columns(0).ColumnName & " ASC"
    End If
```

This functions because I have a hidden column in my `DataGridView` that's always in column-index position 0.  It is an integer primary key for the underlying data that happens to be sorted on data-load.

*You may have to name your index column in the `DataTable` if you haven't already (e.g., `dt_Sender.Columns(0).ColumnName = "colIndex"`).

*If you use a `BindingSource` object as an intermediary between your `DataGridView` and your `DataTable` (as many people seem to do), then you'll have to nest your `DirectCast` appropriately in the second line (i.e., `Dim dt_Sender As DataTable = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, DataTable)` would change to something like: `Dim dt_Sender As DataTable = DirectCast(DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource), DataTable)`).

*Additionally, if your `DataTable` happens to be populated by a SQL Server query that doesn't have an integer primary key (perhaps a GUID?), then you could alter its source query to include a new row number and then hide the new column in your `DataGridView`.  E.g.:

```
SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT '')) AS RowNumber, Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM SourceTable
```

Hopefully this solution is helpful to someone else in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
/// C#
/// Author : Jeudi Prando

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in this.DataGridView1.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
}
```